# Unable to set onItemSelectedListener for spinner in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner

This is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener {

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sort_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.sort_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerAadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAadapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

    }
}
```

Here I want to set onItemClickListener for spinner. I have tried by creating a Inner class and by creating a anonymous class, I have even tried implementing AdapterView.onItemSelectedListener and passing

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

But every way android studio gives me compile-time error.
What can be the possible and correct way to setOnItemSelected for spinner and How?

error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25uWI.png)

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sort_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.sort_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerAadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAadapter);
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Using anonymous class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener {

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sort_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.sort_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerAadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAadapter);
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

    }
}
```

Using inner class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener{

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sort_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.sort_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerAadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAadapter);
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new spinner_class());
     }

    @Override
    public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

    }

    public class spinner_class implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    }
}
```

This way there is no way error but is it correct:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener{

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sort_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.sort_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerAadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAadapter);
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) new spinner_class());
     }

    @Override
    public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

    }
    public class spinner_class implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the error say ?

Comment: Welcome to the community. You may wish to attach error logs also...

Comment: error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/25uWI.png

Comment: The code and error in your question does not match the the screenshot. Please be specific as to what exactly is your problem, and make sure to post your current code as text.

Comment: click != selected... close as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add setOnItemClickListener in your oncreate method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener {

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sort_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.sort_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerAadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAadapter);

       spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 Log.d(TAG,"@@@setOnItemClickListener position:"+position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet (because neither error message nor exact method `setOnItemSelectedListener` call location in code is known) that you have to implement `OnItemSelectedListener`, **not** `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` interface in `MainActivity`. Described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener).